# Saving dataset to txt file

Tags: printing, dataset, report

Im wondering if anyone can tell me how I would save a dataset to a txt file?

Im trying to create a receipt and after many failed attempts of trying to use reportviewer and print it that way I have decided that I will export all my data a txt file and hopefully find an easier way to print it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to specify more details. No real answer is possible otherwise.

Comment: what domain and programming language your are using?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that I am coding in vb. I have basic knowledge of how to write to a txt file but I just dont know how to write a dataset into the txt file.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify the language you are using. here i'm using C# coding

```
  foreach (DataRow row in myDataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        foreach (object item in row.ItemArray)
        {
            myStreamWriter.Write((string)item + "\t");
        }
        myStreamWriter.WriteLine();
    }
```

it is better that you export your data to xml format.

dataset have a method for this work :

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet(); 
ds.WriteXml(fileName);
```

you can read a xml and fill dataset data like below :

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet(); 
ds.ReadXml(fileName);
```